# PHP fopen($file) $file needs escaping?

Tags: php

I'm working on something to get some id3 tags off my media server. I have a method I found for digging ID3 tags out of mp3's

```
<?php
// From here: http://www.autistici.org/ermes/index.php?pag=1&post=15
// and fixed here: http://www.barattalo.it
// ------------------------------
// example:
// print_r( tagReader ("myfile.mp3") );
// ------------------------------
function tagReader($file){
    $id3v23 = array("TIT2","TALB","TPE1","TRCK","TDRC","TLEN","USLT");
    $id3v22 = array("TT2","TAL","TP1","TRK","TYE","TLE","ULT");
    $fsize = filesize($file);
    $fd = fopen($file,"r");
    $tag = fread($fd,$fsize);
    $tmp = "";
    fclose($fd);
    if (substr($tag,0,3) == "ID3") {
        $result['FileName'] = $file;
        $result['TAG'] = substr($tag,0,3);
        $result['Version'] = hexdec(bin2hex(substr($tag,3,1))).".".hexdec(bin2hex(substr($tag,4,1)));
    }
    if($result['Version'] == "4.0" || $result['Version'] == "3.0"){
        for ($i=0;$i<count($id3v23);$i++){
            if (strpos($tag,$id3v23[$i].chr(0))!= FALSE){
                $pos = strpos($tag, $id3v23[$i].chr(0));
                $len = hexdec(bin2hex(substr($tag,($pos+5),3)));
                $data = substr($tag, $pos, 9+$len);
                for ($a=0;$a<strlen($data);$a++){
                    $char = substr($data,$a,1);
                    if($char >= " " && $char <= "~") $tmp.=$char;
                }
                if(substr($tmp,0,4) == "TIT2") $result['Title'] = substr($tmp,4);
                if(substr($tmp,0,4) == "TALB") $result['Album'] = substr($tmp,4);
                if(substr($tmp,0,4) == "TPE1") $result['Author'] = substr($tmp,4);
                if(substr($tmp,0,4) == "TRCK") $result['Track'] = substr($tmp,4);

                if(substr($tmp,0,4) == "TDRC") $result['Year'] = substr($tmp,4);
                if(substr($tmp,0,4) == "TLEN") $result['Lenght'] = substr($tmp,4);
                if(substr($tmp,0,4) == "USLT") $result['Lyric'] = substr($tmp,7);
                $tmp = "";
            }
        }
    }
    if($result['Version'] == "2.0"){
        for ($i=0;$i<count($id3v22);$i++){
            if (strpos($tag,$id3v22[$i].chr(0))!= FALSE){
                $pos = strpos($tag, $id3v22[$i].chr(0));
                $len = hexdec(bin2hex(substr($tag,($pos+3),3)));
                $data = substr($tag, $pos, 6+$len);
                for ($a=0;$a<strlen($data);$a++){
                    $char = substr($data,$a,1);
                    if($char >= " " && $char <= "~") $tmp.=$char;
                }
                if(substr($tmp,0,3) == "TT2") $result['Title'] = substr($tmp,3);
                if(substr($tmp,0,3) == "TAL") $result['Album'] = substr($tmp,3);
                if(substr($tmp,0,3) == "TP1") $result['Author'] = substr($tmp,3);
                if(substr($tmp,0,3) == "TRK") $result['Track'] = substr($tmp,3);
                if(substr($tmp,0,3) == "TYE") $result['Year'] = substr($tmp,3);
                if(substr($tmp,0,3) == "TLE") $result['Lenght'] = substr($tmp,3);
                if(substr($tmp,0,3) == "ULT") $result['Lyric'] = substr($tmp,6);
                $tmp = "";
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

and subsequest call

```
print_r(tagReader("/mnt/data/downloads/music/Arctic Monkeys/Who The F Are Arctic Monkeys_ - EP/05 Who The F Are Arctic Monkeys_.mp3"));
```

I copied this file into a simpler path (even with spaces), and the method works correctly. It doesn't seem to be working with the long file name. I tried escaping the spaces with `\`, but that didn't work.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Are you sure the file is readable and exists?

Comment: Please enable error reporting and display: `error_reporting(-1); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` Then do the same again for the case you've got the error. I assume you'll get an error message then you can add to your question.

Comment: Does your web server's userID have permission to read from /mnt/data?

Comment: this is a magic system, where system calls always return with success

Comment: Well that class does not have even any kind of error handling for file I/O, so it's really made for such a magic system ;)

Comment: Hey guys. I'll set the error reporting, I didn't know that was possible! Certainly will make things a lot easier. I should have permission to read from /mnt/data, as this is my dd-wrt router hooked up to my external hard drive.

Comment: With errors, I got 
'Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 8388608 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 13484377 bytes) in /opt/share/www/hi.php on line 16'
So I added
'ini_set("memory_limit","20M");'
And it fixed it. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually posted a comment up above, I ended turning on error reporting. With errors, I got `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 8388608 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 13484377 bytes) in /opt/share/www/hi.php on line 16` So I added `ini_set("memory_limit","20M");` And it fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Neat little script!  I do some media processing of MP3's with PHP myself for a popular media sharing site, and we've always relied on command-line tools to read ID3 tags.  I've never gotten a script to read those tags just within PHP.

Anyway, escaping of the path isn't needed.  PHP communicates it properly to the underlying OS without that.

I recreated the `/mnt/data/...` path you gave, and put an MP3 file of my own there, with the exact same filename as you gave.  I also turned on error reporting by adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of the script.  The script had no errors and it properly showed the ID3 tags in my MP3 file.

It looks to me that the file wasn't at the path you thought it was, or perhaps there was a problem with your `/mnt/data` mount point.  Have you checked these things?  You can check if PHP is able to see and read the file with the following script:

```
<?php
    $path = "/mnt/data/downloads/music/Arctic Monkeys/Who The F Are Arctic Monkeys_ - EP/05 Who The F Are Arctic Monkeys_.mp3";
    if (!is_file($path)) {
        throw new Exception("No such file");
    } else if (!is_readable($path)) {
        throw new Exception("Path exists, but is not readable");
    }
?>
```